# cattr_accessor in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im reading the Rails guides for Rails 3 and they use this method:

```
cattr_accessor :attribute
```

What is this method? Is it a Rails method? I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is a rails thing. Basically like the attr_* methods, but for the class level. One thing you wouldn't expect is because it uses a backing @@ variable, the value shared between the class and all instances.

```
class Foo
  cattr_accessor :bar
end
# => [:bar] 
foo1 = Foo.new
# => #<Foo:0x4874d90> 
foo2 = Foo.new
# => #<Foo:0x4871d48> 
foo1.bar = 'set from instance'
# => "set from instance" 
foo2.bar
# => "set from instance" 
Foo.bar
# => "set from instance"
```

Comment: Many thanks! I couldn't find that method in current API documentation so it has to be in Rails 3 only?

Comment: according to apidock.com, its been around since 2.1 :)

Comment: Would be good to mention that `class_attribute` is typically a better solution

Answer (score 17):

For those that stumble across this question too, there is a new way to do this in Rails 3 that works for subclasses:

```
class_attribute :name
```

A good blog post on it [here](http://blog.obiefernandez.com/content/2010/04/tr3w-highlights-activesupport-class-class-attribute.html).

Answer (score 7):

Defines both class and instance accessors for class attributes

```
class Person
  cattr_accessor :hair_colors
end

Person.hair_colors = [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
Person.hair_colors     # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
Person.new.hair_colors # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
```

If a subclass changes the value then that would also change the value for parent class. Similarly if parent class changes the value then that would change the value of subclasses too.

```
class Male < Person
end

Male.hair_colors << :blue
Person.hair_colors # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red, :blue]
```

but for Rails 4+ use similar method mattr_accessor, as cattr_accessor is deprecated in rails 4

Comment: copy paste from offcial site..not even change a single word to explain.

Answer (score 1):

This has been deprecated in recent Rails Version. 
http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor

Comment: It's simply caled `mattr_accessor` now.