# understanding the usage of cattr_accessor in Rails Model Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-gem

I am a newbie to Ruby and Rails.
In my Rails app, I am trying to use Wicked Wizard gem and need some help in Understanding about the cattr_accessor which I have come across in  the code

```ruby
# migration
create_table "pets", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "colour"
  t.string   "owner_name"
  t.text     "identifying_characteristics"
  t.text     "special_instructions"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "password"
end

# model
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pet_photos

  cattr_accessor :form_steps do
    %w(identity characteristics instructions)
  end

  attr_accessor :form_step

  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :name, :owner_name, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:identity) }
  validates :identifying_characteristics, :colour, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:characteristics) }
  validates :special_instructions, presence: true, if: -> { required_for_step?(:instructions) }

  def required_for_step?(step)
    return true if form_step.nil?
    return true if self.form_steps.index(step.to_s) <= self.form_steps.index(form_step)
  end
end

# controller
class Pet::StepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps *Pet.form_steps

  def show
    @pet = Pet.find(params[:pet_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @pet = Pet.find(params[:pet_id])
    @pet.update(pet_params(step))

    if params[:images]
      params[:images].each do |image|
        @pet.pet_photos.create(image: image)
      end
    end

    render_wizard @pet
  end

  private

  def pet_params(step)
    permitted_attributes = case step
                           when "identity"
                             [:name, :owner_name]
                           when "characteristics"
                             [:colour, :identifying_characteristics]
                           when "instructions"
                             [:special_instructions]
                           end

    params.require(:pet).permit(permitted_attributes).merge(form_step: step)
  end
end

# routes
PetThing::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pets, only: [:new, :create, :index, :destroy] do
    resources :steps, only: [:show, :update], controller: 'pet/steps'
  end

  root to: 'pets#index'
end
```

Now my Questions are:

**1)** what is the difference between the `cattr_accessor` and `attr_accessor`?

```ruby
       cattr_accessor :form_steps do
         %w(identity characteristics instructions)
       end
       attr_accessor :form_step
```

**2)** why two different symbols(`:form_steps` , `:form_step`) are used as method parameters for  `cattr_accessor` and `attr_accessor` methods respectively?

**3)** why is a block passed as a parameter to `cattr_accessor` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cattr\_accessor in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411403/cattr-accessor-in-rails)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this method is deprecated or moved.
Which version do you use, Rails 4 or Rails ?

`cattr_accessor` > replaced for `mattr_accessor(*syms, &blk)` for `Module` which is the superclass of the class `Class`. I recomend to use **attr_accessor**, which is just a method to set attributes for the class, it works like a getter or a setter for the class but only works for an instance (in memory), the attribute is saved anywhere.

`cattr_accessor` is like the `attr_*` methods, but for the class level. One thing you wouldn't expect is because it uses a backing `@@form_steps`, the value shared between the class and all instances.

#### Api docs:

Defines both class and instance accessors for class attributes.

```
module HairColors
  mattr_accessor :hair_colors
end

class Person
  include HairColors
end

Person.hair_colors = [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
Person.hair_colors     # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
Person.new.hair_colors # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
```

If a subclass changes the value then that would also change the value for parent class. Similarly if parent class changes the value then that would change the value of subclasses too.

```
class Male < Person
end

Male.hair_colors << :blue
Person.hair_colors # => [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red, :blue]
```

To opt out of the instance writer method, pass instance_writer: false. To opt out of the instance reader method, pass instance_reader: false.

```
module HairColors
  mattr_accessor :hair_colors, instance_writer: false, instance_reader:             false
end

class Person
  include HairColors
end

Person.new.hair_colors = [:brown]  # => NoMethodError
Person.new.hair_colors             # => NoMethodError
```

Or pass `instance_accessor: false`, to opt out both instance methods.

```
module HairColors
  mattr_accessor :hair_colors, instance_accessor: false
end

class Person
  include HairColors
end

Person.new.hair_colors = [:brown]  # => NoMethodError
Person.new.hair_colors             # => NoMethodError
```

Also you can pass a block to set up the attribute with a default value.

```
module HairColors
  mattr_accessor :hair_colors do
[:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
  end
end

class Person
  include HairColors
end

Person.class_variable_get("@@hair_colors") #=> [:brown, :black, :blonde, :red]
```

**1)**

- attr_accessor: is a ruby method that makes a getter and a setter
- cattr_accessor:is a ruby method that makes a getter and a setter for the class (quite strange).

**2)**
Class variable have a tendency to wander from class to class. @@form_steps class variable can be exposed through inheritance tree.

**3)** To set which attributes will have this class. `form_steps`

```
p = Pet.new
p.form_steps = "var"
```

and use the `form_steps` attribute inside your current instance Pet (like you do in the method `required_for_step?`).